# Efficient way to check adjacent tiles in a grid in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

So, I want be able to detect adjacent tiles in a grid in which each tile has a `data-id` attribute starting by 1.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jf3dxww0/1/)

This is the code:

**HTML**

```
<div class="grid"></div>
```

**JS**

```
var rows = 7;
var cols = 9;
var size = 50;

$('.grid').css({
    width: size*rows+'px',
  height: size*cols+'px'
});

for(var i = 0; i < rows*cols; i++){
    $('.grid').append('<div class="tile" data-id="'+(i+1)+'" style="width: '+size+'px; height: '+size+'px"><span>'+(i+1)+'</span></div>');
}

function checkAdjacentPossibilities(id){
    i = parseInt(id);
    var array = [];
    if(i==1){
    array.push(false, false, true, true)
    }else if (i>1 && i<rows){
        array.push(false, true, true, true);
    }else if (i==rows){
        array.push(false, true, false, true);
    }else if (i%rows==1 && i>1 && i<(rows*cols)-rows){
        array.push(true, false, true, true);
    }else if(i==(rows*cols)-rows+1){
        array.push(true, false, true, false);
    }else if(i>(rows*cols)-rows+1 && i < rows*cols){
        array.push(true, true, true, false);
    }else if(i==rows*cols){
        array.push(true, true, false, false);
    }else if(i%rows==0 && i>rows && i<rows*cols){
        array.push(true, true, false, true);
    }else{
        array.push(true, true, true, true);
    }

  $('.tile').css('background', 'transparent');

  for(var n = 0; n < array.length; n++){
    var index = n;
    var value = array[n];

    if(value){
        if(index==0){
            $('.tile[data-id="'+(i-rows)+'"]').css('background', 'red');
      }else if(index==1){
        $('.tile[data-id="'+(i-1)+'"]').css('background', 'red');
      }else if(index==2){
        $('.tile[data-id="'+(i+1)+'"]').css('background', 'red');
      }else{
        $('.tile[data-id="'+(i+rows)+'"]').css('background', 'red');
      }
    }


  }

}

$(document).on('click', '.tile', function(){
    var $this  = $(this);
  var id = $this.attr('data-id');
  checkAdjacentPossibilities(id);
});
```

I hardcoded all the 9 possibilities into an if/else statement:

- 4 corners
- top tiles
- left tiles
- bottom tiles
- right tiles
- center blocks

Is there a more efficient way of doing this? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those checks aren't necessary. jQuery does any work on an element if it exists. So here all you have to do is when to change color.

```
function checkAdjacentPossibilities(id){
  i = parseInt(id);
  $('.tile').css('background', 'transparent');
  $('.tile[data-id="'+(i-rows)+'"]').css('background', 'red');
  (i-1) % rows === 0 || $('.tile[data-id="'+(i-1)+'"]').css('background', 'red');
  i % rows === 0 || $('.tile[data-id="'+(i+1)+'"]').css('background', 'red');
  $('.tile[data-id="'+(i+rows)+'"]').css('background', 'red');
}
```

check the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jf3dxww0/2/)

**Update**

Follow the same procedure to save the adjacent cells

```
var adjacentCells = [];
function changeCellColor(adjacentCells) {
  adjacentCells.forEach(function(id) {
    $('.tile[data-id="' + id + '"]').css('background', 'red');
  })
}
function checkAdjacentPossibilities(id){
  i = parseInt(id);
  $('.tile').css('background', 'transparent');
  adjacentCells.push(i - rows, i + rows);
  (i-1) % rows !== 0 &&  adjacentCells.push(i - 1);
  i % rows !== 0 &&  adjacentCells.push(i + 1);
  changeCellColor(adjacentCells);
}
```

check the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jf3dxww0/3/)

Comment: That's clever, but what if I need the array to check other stuff?

Comment: @PeterZelak you could query the tiles with red background and rebuild array however you need

Comment: would it take more time to query the tiles with red background or simply execute the if/else?

Comment: @PeterZelak check my updated answer. `adjacentCells` will contain the red cells. If you need to save all the red cells then do maintain a master array and push every `adjacentCells` array into it.

Comment: @PeterZelak When more time is just a few milliseconds, it should be more important to make the code understandable and short instead of efficient. If you truly want it to be the most efficient possible, you should keep an array or bi-dimensional array with all tiles in it so you don´t even need to query to find them